# How write in my own bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script and want to write something in it for use in the next time:

```
#this get the full path of the script
SCRIPT="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )/$(basename $0)"

NUMBER=10

#This change only in the first occurrence 
cat "$SCRIPT" | sed "1,/NUMBER=../s/NUMBER=../NUMBER=$((NUMBER + 1))/" > "$SCRIPT"
```

The problem I am having is that it produce an empty file. Can I overwrite my bash script in your own code?

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/028](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> cat "$SCRIPT" | ... > "$SCRIPT"
> ```

Don't do this. It will only lead to pain and suffering. And don't write self-modifying code **at all** if you can help it. But if you must, write to a temporary file first and rename after.

Answer (score 1):

Using temp file can save the situation:

```
#this get the full path of the script
SCRIPT="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )/$(basename $0)"

NUMBER=10

#This change only in the first occurrence 
sed "1,/NUMBER=../s/NUMBER=../NUMBER=$((NUMBER + 1))/" "$SCRIPT" > temp.tmp
cat temp.tmp > "$SCRIPT"
rm temp.tmp
```

But it's really interesting if there's a way to solve the problem without temp file:)

Comment: `cat "$SCRIPT" | sed "1,/NUMBER=../s/NUMBER=../NUMBER=$((NUMBER + 1))/" | sponge "$SCRIPT"` (command `sponge` from moreutils)

Comment: All these Useless Uses of Cats!

Comment: Right, you don't need the invocation of `cat`. Sorry for that.

Comment: It's not our's, it was copied from the topicstarter's message:)